# Specific Stripe payment use case scenario

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have this specific scenario and I need some help on how to achieve it:

Stripe is already integrated into my system and I have some active Stripe subscribers who have previously paid for an annual subscription.

Now, I aim to create a Stripe product, not a subscription, priced at $200 for a one-year renewal. If a customer purchases this new product, I intend for my system to utilize the Stripe API to extend their existing and valid subscription by an additional year.

To elaborate, I am interested in understanding whether the Stripe subscription API offers a mechanism to grant an additional year in advance.

It is important to note that these users are still required to make a payment for this subscription, and the current one must remain valid until its expiration.

That said, after giving considerable thought to potential solutions, I have come up with an idea, and I would appreciate your feedback to determine its viability.

I would be grateful if you could thoroughly consider the steps outlined below:

```
1. I create a new product (not a subscription) costing $200 for a one-year renewal;

2. The user buys this new product (not a subscription) which costs $200;

3. On my end, I listen to webhook events related to this new product;

4. Then, I would change the current subscription end date and extend it one more year without charging the user  (turning off proration ?)

5. Meaning that, I should add 1 year free to their existing subscription, e.g. via a stripe subscription schedule + a coupon for 100% off one phase of their schedule?
```

If there is a simpler way to do it, I would like to know that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify some terminology: "proration" is the term for when Stripe charges or credits your customer during an upgrade to make up for the difference on what they have already paid. The `proration_behavior` that you set during that update call only applies to that specific update, turning off proration during an update would mean that the update doesn't charge or credit anything, but the subscription would still charge your customer as normal going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way would probably be creating a $0 price and switching the subscription to that price for 1 year and then back to the normal one. You can do this with a [subscription schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks). This will mean that updating the subscription is a bit more complex while the schedule is active, but it is an easier lift compared to managing this with something like a 100% coupon.

I would highly recommend that you read through all of Stripe's docs about your chosen solution and then play around with it with [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) in test mode to make sure that you understand how it will work in live mode.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, in my particular case, the user is required to pay for the additional year. From the solution you described, it seems that this will be an extra year provided at no cost, considering the product is priced at $0.00.

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, I thought in your initial post you said you wanted to do a one time charge and then when you got the webhook event you weren't sure what to do. Stripe does not have a direct way to extend a subscription without payment or to say "this one off payment is really a prepayment for that subscription". So what I was suggesting was 1) take one-off payment for $200 2) listen for webhook event 3) when you get the event, create a schedule on your current subscription and add a $0 phase and a phase after that that switches back to normal price.

Comment: I'd recommend writing in to Stripe support or the discord server and describing your use case in more detail for more specific advice on this https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true